# BlazeDS point to point examples using JMSAdapter or custom MessageAdapter

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, jms, message-queue, blazeds

Is there any example of using JMS Queues in BlazeDS as point-to-point communication to a Flex client.

I'm curious in writing a custom MessageAdapter for BlazeDS that is adapting a point-to-point message queue system and I want to understand how it works for JMS Queues which are point-to-point.

The [BlazeDS documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=jms_messaging_2.html#276806) describes JMS Queue support:

> JMS queues are point-to-point, unlike
>   topics which are one-to-many. However,
>   due to the administrative overhead of
>   JMS queues, the JMSAdapter is not the
>   best choice for point-to-point
>   messages between clients. A better
>   choice for point-to-point messaging is
>   to use the ActionScriptAdapter in
>   conjunction with message filtering on
>   the client side. For more information,
>   see Message filtering.